# history.push doesn't redirect in action creator after dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, browser-history

This is my action creator:

```
export const loginUser = (loginData, history) => (dispatch) => {

    axios.post('/signin', loginData)
        .then(res => {
            let FBIdToken = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`;
            localStorage.setItem('FBIdToken', `Bearer ${res.data.token}`);
            axios.default.headers.common['Authorization'] = FBIdToken;
            //doesn't redirect
            history.push('/');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response && err.response.data
            });
        });
}
```

This succeed to login and put the token in the right place in the browser but for a reason,  it doesn't redirect to the home page which is confusing to me

when i log history in the action creator i get the history object

```
{length: 29, action: "PUSH", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
```

I am passing history to the action creator from the component, and it works when i push the path in the component but doesn't work when trying in the action creator!

What is the wrong in passing history as an argument to the action creator and why this differ from using it from the component itself??

EDIT:

component Login

```
const Login = ({ loginUser, history }) => {

    const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setLoginData({
            ...loginData,
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        loginUser(loginData, history);
    }

return(
  <Form /> //can't share all the form jsx cause it is too long!
)

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.user,
        UI: state.UI
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser })(Login);
```

component App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter  >
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <div className="container">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <AuthRoute path="/signup" component={Signup} authenticated={authenticated} />
              <AuthRoute path="/login" component={Login} authenticated={authenticated} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

AuthRoute component:

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, authenticated, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route
            render={props => authenticated ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Component {...props} />}
            {...rest}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you share the component code?

Comment: @PixMach i updated the code, can you check please

Comment: @PixMach but what drive me crazy is that even ```window.location.reload()``` and ```window.location.href``` don't work either

Comment: are you using react-router? if so take history out of the props and do `import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'` and `const history = useHistory()` instead possibly.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js on your Router add this. So it can propagate across all props in your components.

install history:

```
npm i history
```

then create an instance and pass it along Router policy

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

<Router history={history}>
   <Route exact path="/mycomponent" component={MyComponent} />
</Router>
```

Comment: where would history come from exactly ?

Comment: Yes, i was about to ask that question till i find yours @BARNOWL

Comment: @Eddwin Paz  should i install react router to import history from??

Comment: Please, see the updated version of the answer. thanks. (Please mark it as correct if it works for you, this helps me to keep answering more questions)

Comment: @Edwin Paz  sorry this answer still unclear, what is history.js file?? is it a npm package, is it a react-router-dom module, i really still confused

Comment: you dont need a history.js its just and abstraction so you can test it later. But I've updated the answer;

Comment: I use this in a production environment with more than 8 million users. And works fine hehehe.. what error or stack trace does it give you?